# Simple Computer Aided Design

Tags: autocad, sketchup, 3ds-max

I need to create a design mockup something very similar to this: [image: example iamge]

However, I don't have weeks to learn AutoCAD or 3dsmax or Sketchup (time consuming). Is there any easier solution? I've heard that Adobe Fireworks can be used for these type of design mockups?

Comment: I doubt you'll find anything easier than Sketchup. That's quite a complex scene.

Comment: Does it need to be actual 3D, viewable from multiple angles? Or just a single angle? I've dabbled in 3D and I honestly had the easiest time learning POV-ray, which renders based on a text file (example: box { <0,0,0>,<5,5,5> texture {T_Wood1}}... 5 unit wooden cube). It works if you have a certain kind of mindset that's suited for programming and text-based stuff. If you've ever worked in CSS, or played with rainmeter, or written javascript, you can learn 3D this way.

Comment: Yes! That was nice and simple (well, I'm quite used to C, Java, programming so it was easy to learn. Thank you! Too bad I can't choose a comment as the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[3DVIA](http://www.3dvia.com/) also has something, but I don't know if it is any less time consuming than Sketchup.